# what class is this replicated system

Tags: model, cloud, distributed, distributed-system, consistency

A replicated system with a consistency model equal to R = 1, W = 1, N = 5 is given. What class does this system include? AP, PC, AC? And why?

- N = number of nodes that store replicas of data
- W = number of replicas that must be modified, for
  complete the write operations
- R = number of replicas to which access is performed during
  read operations

Comment: This sounds like homework...

Comment: Not exactly, but it's kind of. And it's still knowledge share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `AP` system.

1. Your `N=5`, means your same data will be sync to 5 nodes, so it is a `P` system.

   P means `partition tolarance`, for a distributed system, the node in the network is linked with eachother. But for some reasons, the network maybe separated into serval parts, then the data also be separated. If one data be kept to more than 1 replicas, then it called `P`.
2. Your `W=1`, means your system is not a strong consistency system, because different user app may see different data at the same time, but these data will finally be sync, so it is a weak consistency system. Anyway, we can not say this system is `C`.
3. Your `R=1`, means the data can always be read, so it is `A`.

In a word, it is a `AP` system, just like `Cassandra`.

Comment: Thank you! Precise answer I was looking for.